# Repeated measures analysis of Likert-style question

Tags: repeated-measures, ordinal-data, likert, independence

I have a Likert-style survey that includes 2 questions: perceived understanding *before* an intervention and perceived understanding *after* the intervention. I would like to use some form of inferential statistics to determine if there is a significant improvement in understanding post-intervention.

Issues: Likert-like questions are ordinal (not continuous); and because the same person is answering both questions, the groups (before and after) are not independent.

**What is the correct test to use here?**

I've seen lots of suggestions for Likert tests (Wilcoxon signed-rank test, t-test, ANOVA, Pearson correlation, bootstrapping, mixed modelling, etc.), but no posts I've seen seem to give a reasonable answer to my simple scenario. I understand there may be disagreement on the *proper* approach, but can anybody point me toward an acceptable approach and briefly explain its application?

Comment: What's wrong with the suggestions you have? Simplest is the Wilcoxon test. It looks at the change.

Comment: @DifferentialPleiometry the audience = college-level educational researchers (an unfamiliar field to me, btw)

Comment: @JeremyMiles I have seen these multiple tests suggested in many contexts (most different form my own), but in no instance were my concerns (ordinal + dependent) and interests (inferential significance test) all exemplified. So, really, I'm just left unsure if any one of them *is* in fact a reasonable and appropriate approach.

Comment: I am not familiar with that target audience to know how to tailor a response specifically to them, but hopefully my answer below will serve the purpose if no one brings a better answer to your attention.

Comment: A sign test, not ranked sign test, is suitable to compare paired samples whilst respecting the ordinal nature of the data.

Comment: I recommend reading [*Nominal, ordinal, interval, ratio: Stevens’ typology and some problems with it*](https://medium.com/peter-flom-the-blog/nominal-ordinal-interval-ratio-stevens-typology-and-some-problems-with-it-93b1033815f7) by our very own Peter Flom.

Answer (score 4):

Ordinal variables, considered within [Stevens' typology](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.103.2684.677), can be operated on in a way that preserves the [action](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupAction.html) of a certain [group](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Group.html) (called an isotonic group in Stevens' 1946 paper). We will avoid this underlying theory below.

I do not believe there is a uniquely-best way to answer your question, but here is a conceptually simple approach that steers clear of sophisticated or complicated arguments.

Let's say you have your survey question denoted $x_{i,b}$ for the $i$th participant *before* the intervention, and for that same participant you have their response to the survey question $x_{i,a}$ *after* the intervention. Since the survey questions are on a Likert scale, we know that $x_{i,b} \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $x_{i,a} \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Ordinal variables have one clear property: order. This means we can compare $x_{i,b} < x_{i,a}$, $x_{i,b} > x_{i,a}$, or their non-strict analogs. You could also consider $x_{i,b} = x_{i,a}$ for that matter.

Let's say you are interested in how often the participants' survey response was higher after the intervention. You can then compute the frequency probability as

$$P(X_b < X_a) \approx \frac{\text{Count}(x_b < x_a)}{n}$$

where $\text{Count}(x_b < x_a)$ is the number of participants whose intervention survey score was higher than their pre-intervention survey score, and $n$ is the number of participants.

Sometimes it is sufficient to just consider this probability, especially if it is close to zero or one. But there is a lot of variation among people, so one might wish to bootstrap this probability to inspect a histogram and confidence interval.

The probability itself is a way of quantifying the effect of the intervention, addressing your concern about non-independence in a particular way. Because the inequalities were evaluated in a way paired by the participants, you have addressed their role in answering both the before and after questions. Since we stuck to a simple frequency of how often an inequality held among participants, we have not violated Steven's typology by fallaciously treating the Likert scales as ratio or interval variables.

Comment: (+1) Note that under the null hypothesis of no intervention effect $\text{Count}(x_b < x_a) \sim \mathcal{Bin}\left(n^*, \frac{1}{2}\right)$ (where $n^* = \text{Count}(x_b \neq x_a)$ is the no. non-tied before/after pairs): the basis of the [sign test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_test).

Comment: +1 certainly gives me an alternative way to think about this. Thanks!